# My cherry-pick deletes a single file, which does exist on the target, yet it does not auto complete. Why?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have a commit that deletes a single file:

```
C:\xyz\tmp55 [55 ↑1]> git show 17e645494
commit 17e6454949b44911bc42135e8f12c7f169ef835f
Author: Mark Kharitonov <bla-bla-bla>
Date:   Mon Nov 12 11:05:18 2018 -0500

    Some changes on MarkFeature

diff --git a/New Text Document.txt b/New Text Document.txt
deleted file mode 100644
index e69de29bb..000000000
```

The file exists on the target:

```
C:\xyz\tmp55 [55 ↑1]> dir '.\New Text Document.txt' -Name
New Text Document.txt
```

Yet the cherry-pick fails to auto complete:

```
C:\xyz\tmp55 [55 ↑1]> git cherry-pick 17e64549
warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
warning: you may want to set your merge.renamelimit variable to at least 7501 and retry the command.
error: could not apply 17e645494... Some changes on MarkFeature
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
C:\xyz\tmp55 [55 ↑1 +0 ~0 -0 !1 | +0 ~0 -1 !]>
```

Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps the content of the file has changed? In that case a conflict is to be expected.

Comment: Yes, the content may be different, but does it matter when the file is deleted?

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, it seems likely. It would not have conflicted otherwise. Mark, you just need to remove the file from index (with `git rm`) and commit.

Comment: I know how to resolve it. I want to understand what is going on

Comment: @eftshift0 You are right. I changed the content of the file to match exactly the delete one and it passed. Please, arrange your comment as the answer so I could credit you.

Comment: Posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the file has probably changed and it makes sense that you get a conflict then. Imagine the situation. You delete a file on a branch, on another branch someone changed the file.... what should be the result when merging? A conflict is to be expected.